# Apache POI: Data is not visible in XLSX after updating POI version from 3.10 to 5.2.2

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, apostrophe

I was updating POI library from 3.10 to 5.2.2 after reported vulnerabilities in previous version.

I updated all the functions, classes according to the documentation and after all the changes .xlsx file also got generated but it's content is not visible in MS excel, how ever it is visible in some of the online editors and in openOffice I have to select default format to get the content visible.

Observations:

1. All the values are treated as formula in excel because there is '(apostrophe) in each value, hence not visible.
2. in OpenOffice values are visible, and in formula bar(with the apostrophe)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/squo3.png).

Comment: I doubt this will be answerable without having the code which sets the cell values (... uses `Cell.setCellValue`). It seems you set time values as string, hence the apostrophes in OpenOffice. But that should not lead to invisibility in Excel. Btw.: "All the values are treated as formula in excel because there is '(apostrophe) in each value, hence not visible.": This is a wrong conclusion.

Comment: Yes you are write, the problem was with the format of the data and I have fixed the issue. The Data was not visible because it's font was not set so, it was taking it as white(may be). I set it to black and it worked.